# Associate file type with unlisted application in Ubuntu desktop/file manager?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a java program on my computer 'STM32CubeMX' that works with '.mxproject' files but I am unable to make a file association so they can be double clicked.

When I select 'Open With Other Application' then 'View All Applications' to make the association STM32CubeMX is nowhere to be found.

Any Ideas how I can either add it to the list of recognized applications or do some other workaround to enable opening projects by double clicking?